# How to create Splashscreen launch Multiple Default Start files optimized for each render engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, scatter-objects-addon

I'd like to have the option of launching Blender then from the Splash screen, choosing a pre-configured optimized default scene for Cycles, Eevee and also the default startup scene.
example:
Launch blender, Default scene is EEVEE with all the best settings.
Launch blender, Default scene is CYCLES with all the best settings.
Launch blender, Default scene is Blender Default.

Comment: It is described in the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html)

Comment: **Application Template**s are the very thing to use for this situation.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html